# Do protobuf-net supports protobuf extensions?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a base.proto with a set of messages that can be extensible using  [protobuff extensions](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#choosing-extension-numbers), then I have a comm.proto that extends some of the messages defined in base.proto.

I used ProtoGen to generate base.cs and comm.cs files but I am not able to access the extension fields added by comm.cs.

Is this supported or I have to pass some extra parameter to ProtoGen?

Best regards 
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on which version of protogen you are using.

The protogen tool was *completely rewritten* as part of the 2.3.0 work that added proto3 support (still retaining proto2),  with full codegen support of *expected* extension fields (meaning: extensions declared in .proto etc) added at the same time.

Note that *runtime* support of *unexpected* fields has been there for a long time - the easiest way to access them is via static methods on the `Extensible` type.

Comment: I have a version previous to 2.3.0 because I am not able to build 2.3.2 with mono develop, because of the format of the .Net Project.

Any suggestion to build 2.3.2 protobuf-net with Mono on MacOS? It would be great you/or someone provides a mono versions the binaries to use out-of-the-box.

Thank you for your reply

Comment: @posilva you're not wrong; I should find the time to do that. Is `dotnet build` not an option by any chance? To emphasize: one of the key reasons for the rewrite was *precisely* to improve the x-plat story... (The previous version was even more platform bound).

Comment: can you give me some highlights about how use `dotnet build`  to build version 2.3.2.

My environment is: 

- MacOS  
- I intend to use protobuf-net in a Unity Project to target mobile and webgl.
- I have dotnet sdk 2.0.3 installed 

When I run `dotnet build protobuf-net.sln` I got ` The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found`

Thank you in advance

Comment: @posilva you should be able to use `dotnet build -f netstandard1.3` in the protobuf-net folder?

Comment: Did not work I keep getting `Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netstandard1.3' in the TargetFrameworks for your project`. :(. Any thoughts?  I will keep digging. If I can find the solution I will share here the answer.

Comment: I was able to compile protobuf-net.dll but fails to build protogen:
`CSC : error CS0009: Metadata file '/Users/pedro.silva/System/Develop/projects/build/protobuf-net/src/protobuf-net/bin/Debug/netstandard1.3/protobuf-net.dll' could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata. [/Users/pedro.silva/System/Develop/projects/build/protobuf-net/src/protobuf-net.Reflection/protobuf-net.Reflection.csproj]`
There are several errors like this in the reflection project but are 625 lines of errors.

Comment: Got 625 errors similar to this:`Descriptor.cs(334,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/pedro.silva/System/Develop/projects/build/protobuf-net/src/protobuf-net.Reflection/protobuf-net.Reflection.csproj]
`

Comment: @posilva k; I think I'm going t have to try to repro this locally and take a look at the build. What are your mono / unity versions? (and any other relevant info) - so I can try to set it up?

Comment: I will open a ticket in the [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) github project , that allows to add more info than in the comment. I will point to this discussion and the outcome will be posted here.

Comment: Opened an issue in the project with details:  https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/321